# Delphi method signature conversion to c#

Tags: c#, delphi, delphi-2007

I have this signature in a delphi 2007 function I'm calling (the SomeOtherFile is another DLL that it in turn is calling):

```
function MyFunction(Place, Name: PChar):_Recordset; stdcall; far; external 'SomeOtherFile.DLL';
```

I'm trying to call it from C# code like this:

```
[DllImport("MyFile.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint="MyFunction")]

public static extern DataSet MyFunction(string Place, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string Name);
```

Whenever I run this and store it into a variable, I get a runtime error about type mismatches. I guess I'm reading the signature wrong, but I can't figure out what it should be.

*edit*
The actual error is: A call to PInvoke function [...] has unbalanced the stack...I've also tried both params using the MarshalAs attribute, and it throws the same thing.

Comment: "Type mismatch" is usually a compile-time error, not a run-time error. Can you please quote the error text and tell us the class name of the error you get? Also, what makes you think the second parameter needs to be marshaled specially but the first does not? What does `MyFunction` do with those pointers? (Does it write into the buffers, or does it only read from them?) Finally, what are `DataSet` and `_Recordset`?

Comment: It's pretty hard to see the P/Invoke marshaller matching up `_Recordset` and `DataSet`! You also don't need the `MarshalAs` attribute either, but that's a nuance.

Comment: @Dan why you are using `MarshalAs` in the `Name` parameter and not in the `Place`, if both parameters are the same type?

Comment: @RRUZ but you don't need it in either since it is the default marshalling for string parameters. What's more it's possible for two parameters of the same type to need different marshalling: consider an IN PChar parameter and an OUT PChar parameter.

Comment: @David but in this case the function is declarated as `function MyFunction(Place, Name: PChar)` not `function MyFunction(Place, var Name: PChar)` So I wondering why the OP is using `MarshalAs` if both parameters are equals.

Comment: @RRUZ both an IN and an OUT string parameter would usually be typed PChar. Knowing the type is not enough to know how to call it. My point is that repeating the default marshalling seems odd. I guess your point is to try and tease out if there is something different in the marshalling of the two params that OP is not letting on about. All of which pales in comparison to the function return value problem!

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bit of digging around and I think you need to marshal the return value as a `Recordset` interface. I'm sure the P/Invoke marshaller won't magically convert your Delphi `_Recordset` into a .net `DataSet` class instance.

So I think you can write it something like this:

```
[DllImport("MyFile.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
public static extern object MyFunction(string Place, string Name);
```

Call it like this

```
Recordset rs = (Recordset) MyFunction(Place, Name);
```

I'm assuming that the `Place` and `Name` parameters are input parameters, in which case the default marshalling for string is just fine.

You don't need to specify ANSI character set because that is the default too. You don't need to name the entry point if it has the same name as the C# function.  You don't need to specify the calling convention because `stdcall` is the default.

The [`Recordset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adodb.recordset.aspx) interface resides in the ADODB namespace.

As an aside, the use of `far` in your Delphi function import is spurious. The `far` keyword stopped having any effect once we left the 16 bit world behind.

Comment: Thank you David for your help (and RRUZ too), but I'm getting the same error. If it helps, here's how someone wrote the code in Delphi: Recordset := MyFunction('Home',PChar('Steve')); That second param makes me think my signature is wrong.

Comment: The parameters to the function will be fine. I'm confident that part of the P/Invoke is fine. The issue is surely the RecordSet. I've got another idea. Please bear with me.

Comment: @Dan I've edited the function to be specific on the marshalling of the return value. But I'd be surprised if this changes anything since surely the default marshaller can work out how to marshall in interface pointer. Incidentally, are you 100% sure that the function is using stdcall? Unbalanced stacks also often happen when you mix cdecl and stdcall. What happens why you use cdecl from the C#?